# iOS app crashes with ADMOB banner

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, admob

I have a 2 view aplication, on the main screen I have added ADMOB banner, it works perfectly. But when I click on UIButton (any category) to move to the second UIView, the app crashes and I get error : "thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)" . 
[Picture with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXGDS.png)

When I remove the banner, it works good again. Not sure what Im missing. The whole code is here:
[Picture with whole viewcontroller.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEDFt.png)

Thank you for reply.

Comment: Please include the text as code, not only as screenshot. The problem seems to be `banner` is `nil` - di you correctly connect it in the interface builder?

Comment: Is the crash happening in the ViewController you're moving to?

Comment: @luk2302 yes, I believe I have connected it correctly, not sure if I should erase banner.hidden = true code

Comment: @DanielStorm it crashes when I click on the button which leads to next viewController (next scene)